# Não consigo remover linhas clonadas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar um form dinamico, estou conseguindo clonar normalmente, mas não consigo excluir os itens clonado.
O que tem de errado no meu código?
Nesse caso, com um duplo click na "TR" clonada teria que excluir a linha, mas não funciona em itens clonado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clon").click(function() {
        $(".clonar").clone()
            .appendTo(".lista")
            .attr("class", "clonado")
            .find("input").removeAttr("id");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clonado").dblclick(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1">
    <table>
        <tr class="clonar">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="cod[]" id="cod" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="prod[]" id="prod" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="vlr[]" id="vlr" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="clon" type="button" name="clonar" value="Clonar">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<form name="form2">
    <table class="lista">

    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que esta linha:

```
$(".clonado").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

vai adicionar um auscultador de evento aos elementos que existem naquele momento e não a futuros elementos.

#### Para resolver isso tens duas possibilidades:

Podes adicionar um novo auscultador de evento ao elemento clonado assim:

```
$(".clonar").clone()
  .dblclick(function(){ $(this).remove(); }) // <------  
  .appendTo(".lista")
  .attr("class","clonado")
  .find("input").removeAttr("id");
```

Ou usas delegação para ele procurar elementos que são adicionados depois:

```
$('form[name="form1"] table').on("dblclick", ".clonado", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```